# Simple jQuery Form Design. I need jQuery Code for Below HTML Form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to the jQuery and I dnt know how to make this simple html form in working stat. What I need is when I select the checkbox the selected option will be shown a side. and when I click on the close button from the list the respective checkbox should uncheck. In short I want synchronize both checkboxes and their option from the list.

[image: HTML Form]

Comment: Check out `click` events, better yet, use a framework that supports data-binding, could probably save you some time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at click events, and use your checkboxes id to play around it :

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click',function(){})...
```

**Full demo here**: http://jsfiddle.net/XESxa/1/

be creative ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('.checkboxselector').click(function(){
    $('#boxholdingtheitemsontheright').append('<some html of your choosing>' + $(this).next().text() + '</close>');
});
```